# How to use resources instead of strings for swagger api annotations in servicestack

Tags: internationalization, servicestack, swagger

I'd like to create servicestack api and use swagger for autoupdatable documentation. The problem is that I need this documentation to be i18n-azied, so the question is, is it possible to do in servicestack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not natively supported but ServiceStack's `SwaggerFeature` does provide model and property filters that let you modify the returned swagger models, i.e. providing an opportunity to substitute the text in the returned models, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature { 
    ModelFilter = model => myLocalize(model),
    ModelPropertyFilter = property => myLocalize(property)
});
```

Whilst it's not heavily used yet, ServiceStack's approach to localizing strings is to route text through to `AppHost.ResolveLocalizedString()` which can be overridden in your AppHost to change what string is returned.